# About a differential of a field

Tags: calculus, field-theory, euler-lagrange-equation

Is the change in a derivative the same as the derivative of the change in a field $\phi$, i.e.

$$\delta(\partial_\mu\phi) = \partial_\mu(\delta \phi)$$

This came up in a Proof of Noether's theorem, when computing the change in the Lagrangian $\delta L$, where $L$ is a function of $\phi$ and its derivates $\partial_\mu \phi$.

Comment: Yes! It is the same

Comment: Could you give me a reference?

Comment: You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)